# Announcing our new Manager, Community Trust & Safety: Cesar M

Tags: discussion, announcements, stack-exchange-team, community-managers

When I joined Stack Overflow (the company, not the site), I was initially asked to work on a nascent Trust and Safety team.  This was a new team for the community department, just formed, at the urging of [CesarM](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/508266/cesar-m), who had been advocating for it for some time.

I like to build stuff, so this appealed to me a lot, and after my initial conversations with Cesar, I was even more excited, because I knew that I would enjoy working with him.  He has a similar (warped) sense of humor to mine, and I knew we would have a good time while being very productive.

Cesar, it was explained to me, was a Senior Community Manager, who was heading up this new team while we figured out how to make it go. And he did a great job with that, managing my own onboarding process, working with me to set goals and determine what was needed, from tools to documentation to staff.

So when I was asked to take on my current role, naturally one of my first moves was to look into how to appropriately resource Cesar, since he was all alone on that team (again).  We did that, and published a couple of vacancy announcements (more on that later this week). One of my next moves was to begin the process of formalizing what was essentially in effect already: to officially make Cesar the manager of our Trust and Safety team, rather than filling the role as a Senior Community Manager.

I’m pleased to announce that as of November 1, we’re promoting Cesar from Senior Community Manager to his new role as Manager, Community Trust & Safety. Later this week, he’ll be introducing you to his new team, as we get our new folks onboard.

While he’s been acting as the team lead for several months, his new position brings with it increased responsibilities around annual planning and prioritization, so I hope you’ll understand if he’s not yet in a position to lay out a detailed plan for you, but I know that you’ll want to join me in congratulating him for this well-deserved promotion.

Comment: Fantastic news... congrats Cesar (and may the lord have mercy on your soul :p)

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I would like to hear a definition of the term "Community Trust & Safety". What does this even mean? I cannot imagine any definition of the term that would be a useful office to have. There are no "safety" risks of participation in the community, and building/maintaining "Community Trust" should be the job of *all* publicly-facing team members, without exception.

Comment: @CodyGray - Trust and Safety is a fairly standard group in most web properties now. They typically deal with things like attempts to compromise accounts, spam waves, and assuring the physical safety of users (ie, from those who threaten or those who would do harm to themselves). They also frequently enforce site Terms or Privacy Policy as well.

Comment: @CodyGray - There's a decent overview of the types of things that a Trust and Safety team does at https://www.tspa.info. Here, the team is largely policy-making and consultative; they don't do as much on the enforcement side of things.

Comment: I surely do hope with increased responsibility comes an inflated paycheck. Although I doubt any amount would be high enough for having to deal with these jQuery jokes.

Comment: @Luuklag - something something I'll make him regret taking the job something something.

Comment: @JitendraSingh maybe better wait until it takes effect, in few days?

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsVaccinatedV3, actually, i didn't feature it on purpose, at Cesar's request.  I think the reasoning is that we have more staff announcements headed out later this week and we're saving it for that.

Comment: @Philippe those are great news! :)

Answer (score 18):

Hail Cesar!!

I really hope your second in command isn’t called Brutus.

It might be an idea to book PTO for the 15th March, just in case.

Comment: Even if he does get assassinated, they'll probably use JQuery and not knives.  Probably.

Comment: @Ollie - "Cause of death?"  "jQuery."  "Yeah, that checks out."

Comment: @Philippe What, like this: `$('Cesar').bind('with ropes',function () {  print("Et tu, Philippe?"); continue(draw-curtain); });`

Comment: @Ollie - Error, (A)bort, (R)etry, (F)ail. :P

Comment: I would take knives over Philippe playing with jQuery.

Comment: You'd be more likely to survive the knife fight, yup.

Comment: Sharp sticks - no good. Sharp knives - perfectly acceptable. But jQuery? Now that's out of line.

Comment: @CesarM Remember to stay away from Philippe on the 15th next year... :D

Comment: For anybody wondering what all the jQuery stuff is about, see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/560258).

Comment: @Ollie- there are a huge number of reasons to thank Shog that I'm not the Manager of Trust and Safety, and my jQuery skills are but the beginning of the list. Don't even get me started on how I can wield BASIC in the service of defeating the dark arts.

Comment: Also, @Ollie - you have forgotten something.  I'm the one who approves his PTO.  March 15th, declined.

Comment: @Philippe Not even if he bribes you with stroopwafels?

Comment: @Philippe I don't think you want to have me taking sick time enough to recover from your jQuery efforts....

Comment: @CesarM  - you're going to run into an upper bound, at least by the number of working days in a year.

Answer (score 13):

I can't think of anything witty to say, so...

About damned time :) He's been *excellent* at picking up the ways of this place, and it also means I guess that the basic framework of all 3 teams is up.

Comment: Thank you for the kind words, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 10):

Congrats, Cesar! It's been a pleasure working with you. Your guidance was very helpful in getting me up to speed as a community manager here. Your new title is well-earned!

I'm looking forward to you continuing to mess with Philippe. Someone's gotta keep him in check... ;)

Comment: *grabs popcorn and sits back to watch*

Comment: Ahem.  "Not a team player."  Got it.

Comment: They're still team players. Just not on your team ? :D

Comment: @JourneymanGeek?  buddy?  Pal?   

Don't help.  :P

Answer (score 2):

Parabéns pá.

> [*pá*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/p%C3%A1#Portuguese)
>
> (personal pronoun of difficult translation, interjection, noun.)
>
> It means shovel, tool, buddy, dude, man - but can be used for any gender.
>
> Humorous, colloquial and informal.

> [*Parabéns* - Congratulations](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/portuguese-english/parabens).

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations Cesar. It will be really exciting for us to see you working here on the Stack Exchange network. Best of luck for the future!