# Please welcome Valued Associates #999 - Bella Blue & #1001 - Salmon of Wisdom

Tags: discussion, announcements, community-managers

Earlier this year, we hired [Philippe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/936316/philippe) to join me on what was the newly created Trust & Safety subteam of the Community Team. He then promptly left me alone again and became [VP of Community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367425/new-vp-of-community-plus-two-more-community-managers) instead. Jokes aside, Philippe was of great help and has been a great person to work with, and we got many things kick-started together. But today I’ve got new friends in town, I’m *very* excited to announce that we have two new CMs joining me on the team.

**[Bella_Blue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1058732/bella-blue)**

Bella has been working in Community Management for 15 years. Starting her career with Myspace, Bella moderated the Religion and Philosophy areas, as well as the Arts and Literature forums until their close. She continued to manage multiple communities - both large and small - throughout her career. In her most recent position, she managed a community of over 1 million unique users dedicated to comics and movies. Bella is passionate about how online communities mold the real world around us, and believes they are to be protected and tended with care and respect.

In her free time, she likes to read and study languages. She is currently learning Korean, and has spent some time answering questions on both the Korean Language and Language Learning Stack Exchange sites.

**[Salmon_of_Wisdom](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1081359/salmon-of-wisdom)**

Salmon is only a little new to Stack Overflow. They have made use of the site’s vast stores of knowledge in their studies (including the very last Flash course given at their school), but have only recently begun to add to the hoard here.

Their community management career began with volunteer moderation and eventually community management for game platforms, but they have a long career in caring and customer service roles as well. Salmon also volunteers for a few small gaming conventions and cannot wait to be part of those communities again.

They leap from interest to hobby quite frequently, but they can currently be found learning to work with deaf dogs and playing bluegrass standards. Past hobbies include playing music journo, chainmailing, and dog photography. (Yes, they would like to see a picture of your pet.)

---

Both Bella_Blue and Salmon have been incredible during onboarding so far and I’m looking forward to getting to work more with them. If you’re curious about what the Trust & Safety team is responsible for, here’s a nonexhaustive (nor exclusive!) list of things we’re looking at: compromised accounts, spam waves, code of conduct violations, technical investigations, improvements to tooling, policies and enforcement process, as well as consulting on privacy, data handling, and compliance. Bella and Salmon will report to me in my new role of [Manager, Community Trust & Safety](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371226/announcing-our-new-manager-community-trust-safety-cesar-m).

Please give them a warm welcome, and to quote Philippe, new CMs are [friends, not food](https://giphy.com/gifs/disney-quote-Le5eHA05wkYCs/)!

Comment: Now I want to know: *who is valued associate #1000?*

Comment: Bella and Salmon are such a joy to work with. We're so happy to have them here. :)

Comment: Welcome to the team! I am really happy to have other two incredible colleagues. It’s a blessing to be in this team and getting to know such interesting people. ❤️
But I am disappointed that Salmon didn’t mention their baking skills! Smh. 

Comment: Employees who deal with spam waves? [There's some folks who'd love to meet them](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq)

Comment: @Machavity Does waving hello in Charcoal HQ count as a spam wave?

Comment: @RyanM Then we'd have to flag the wavers, wouldn't we?

Comment: Salmon doesn't want to brag in any way they can be held accountable =P

Comment: Salmon doesn't want to end up in a terrine ;)

Comment: @ThomasMarkov: Someone from a different department (that isn't really an external-facing role).

Comment: Psyched to see the cadence; hope it continues!

Comment: Psyched to see @Shog9 around :)

Comment: I truly feel honored to be part of this team and to work alongside such brilliant people. But even more than that, I am excited to help serve this amazing community. Thank you all for such a warm welcome. :)

Comment: @Luuklag *Psyched to see Shog9 around :)* absolutely WOW

Comment: Myspace? Now that's a name I haven't heard in a long time...

Comment: "(including the very last Flash course given at their school)" EXCUSE ME? @Salmon_of_Wisdom HELLO I WOULD LIKE TO BE FRIENDS

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn you need to pay more attention, you forgot the exclamation points (for added effect, mix in 1s with the exclamation points) /joke

Comment: @Ekadh Singh the juxtaposition of mentioning "!!1!1" followed by a tone indicator is causing all sorts of cognitive dissonance for me /lh

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Hello, yes, you wanna write some _ActionScript_, like the cool kids used to do?

Comment: @Salmon_of_Wisdom once AS3 support comes to Ruffle, it'll be just like old times (though I shipped my Flash game as recently as 2018). There's always gotoAndStop() for now...

Comment: I still don't get why all these hires are being made yet they let go of Shog?

Comment: @JonH Shog9 currently has a job, they literally cannot hire him.

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica - i understand that - I was trying to say he was doing an EXCELLENT job HERE at SO/SE.  But they let go of him - so I was thinking ok maybe SO/SE is cutting back on people - but instead all I hear week after week is hiring here.  I just don't get it.

Comment: @JonH the increased hirings started around 1.5 years and 1 company sold later.

Comment: Hmmm... Something fishy about this...  

Comment: @JonH Apparently the firing happened right before a pretty big change in management. New hirings have *roughly* been a mix of folks finally realising the current situation was untenable, and actually having the resources to hire again. Frankly the internal workings of SE are opaque, even to the folks who follow what they do closely \o/

Comment: Does Salmon not want to disclose their gender, or is "*they*" their preferred pronoun? They might want to state that on their profile page.

Comment: @Bergi does it really matter?

Comment: @TedWrigley - typically I'm a lover of a good pun. I enjoy the humor.  That one, though..... ::shakes head:: Terrible.  Just terrible.  (It made me lol, though!).   It's great to have both Salmon and Bella around. They add a particular bit of.... je ne sais quois.... to the T&S team.  Plus, they keep Cesar out of my hair. :-)

Comment: @Philippe on the bright side, in some amount (10? 20? Maybe more? Maybe less?) amount of years, you’ll have no more hair, and Cesar can bother you all he wants ;)

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica - don't help. :P

Comment: @Bergi gendered pronouns don't guarantee that someone identifies with that gender, so this isn't really an issue of disclosing gender identity or not. That said, a clear indication of whether to observe they/them pronouns would be helpful - though absent of which, it can be presumed as a default pronoun (and if a user objects to being referred to as they/them, but doesn't state what pronouns to use, then that's on that user).

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Yes, of course. It just seemed that Cesar should know Salmon well enough not having to use a default pronoun for them…

Comment: @Bergi I'd say, very broadly, when someone consistently uses a specific pronoun to refer to someone else and that person hasn't objected to it, you can assume that it is an acceptable or even *the* pronoun to use.

Comment: Given the location of the salmon in @Salmon_of_Wisdom's profile pic, I'm currently contemplating the wisdom of that particular pictured salmon...  Is that too meta for this exchange?

Comment: Thoughts on The Salmon of Doubt @Salmon_of_Wisdom? (I've been meaning to read it for such a long time, but your username made me think of it :)) Also welcome!

Comment: @AudenYoung I haven't read it since I was a fry, which is maybe a sign it's time to re-read it. Thanks for the reminder!

Comment: My wife has a tattoo of the [original](https://oldcurrencyexchange.files.wordpress.com/2015/06/large-small-10p1.jpg?w=300&h=172&crop=1) @Salmon_of_Wisdom from the Irish coins. :-) Welcome to Salmon and Bella!

Comment: Why is this featured again (or it wasn't?)?

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q it’s always been featured. It’s in the revision history. It will most likely be unfeatured in around day after tommorow.

Answer (score 22):

### Congrats and welcome to both of you!

As a semi-new CM myself, I'm glad to see the company continuing to hire more CMs and invest in the community. I'm sure Cesar is happy to have an actual team working with him instead of just handling Trust & Safety stuff all by himself, too :)

I'm looking forward to seeing what y'all do in your time here! I'm especially glad to see the company bringing on others with a long history in community management (whether professionally or as volunteers) to the CM team - I'd love to hear a bit more about your backgrounds if you're willing to share (publicly or privately).

Welcome to the team!

*(PS: Sorry, I don't have any pets to share pictures of...)*

Comment: “I don't have any pets” BLASPHEMY! BUUURRN HIIMMMMM!!1!!1!!1!!I!! <\joke>

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica: I didn't have any growing up because my mom's allergic to both cats and dogs... And she vetoed my request for a snake :P

Comment: @V2Blast I'm sorry I only give information in exchange for cute animal pictures. But I understand your dilemma so, I'll make an exception.  It doesn't have to be your own personal pet. Animals in hats are my favorite. _*see I'm very magnanimous*_  :P

Comment: @Bella_Blue: [How's this?](https://www.boredpanda.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/cute-snakes-wear-hats-106__700.jpg)

Comment: @V2Blast I love it!!! Message me for my lengthy memoirs. _A CM's Life: We're All Mad Here, and We Like it!_

Comment: You stole my book title!

Answer (score 19):

A warm welcome to you both!!

This is Charlie.  5 year old Labrador who we puppy-walked for the [Guide Dogs Charity](https://www.guidedogs.org.uk/).  He was withdrawn on potential health issues, so we gave him our forever home.

[image]

This is Mollie, a 13 year old Miniature Schnauzer.  Partial to fish, sweet potato, cheese and kibble.

[image]

Comment: Just a quick FYI: Although it is not part of my announcement (terrible oversight on my part) I too would appreciate all the pet photos!!! :D

Comment: @Bella_Blue  Please feel free to take emotional ownership of whichever photo you'd like.  My dogs are both willing to share their affections (as long as you smell vaguely of biscuits!).

Comment: No self portraits, please!

Comment: @Bella_Blue My favorite pet: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYg8q.png

Comment: Uh-oh... A dog that is partial to fish? This could be dangerous for a Salmon, wise or not.

Answer (score 11):

Welcome to the team, both of you!

I'm very excited about this part:

> If you’re curious about what the Trust & Safety team is responsible for, here’s a nonexhaustive (nor exclusive!) list of things we’re looking at: compromised accounts, spam waves, etc.

We're [very happy](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59469064#59469064) to hear that.  There are plenty of spam waves to deal with.  The system is already efficient, but with more CMs on the job the spammers will be deleted in droves.  Hope to see you in [Charcoal HQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) often, then!

Good luck to both of you.

Answer (score 11):

Welcome aboard!! It's great to see even more new faces among the CM team.

This is Finley. He's 3 years old now and loves snuggles and produce that's on the verge of going bad. (click for larger images)

[image: Fin_Pic_1] [image: Fin_Pic_2]

Comment: Where y'at?  I'll send you all the tomatoes we screwed up this year ;)

Comment: Haha too many tomatoes and I may not be able to fit on the couch with him anymore! I'll have to turn you down this time, @Ollie :)

Comment: Oh wow! He's grown a bit since I last saw him!

Comment: He's definitely come a long way, @Tink! I think we're finally done with the growing though. Just need to keep him away from nice strangers with tomatoes so he doesn't overeat :p

Comment: Finley is just as precious as I remember him

Comment: He looks like Donald Rump!!

Comment: Please tell Finley that I love him

Comment: I believe that Finley may be one of the most handsome pets that I've seen in a very long time.

Answer (score 10):

## ❤️ →  & ❗

But on a different note: how did you both happen to have underscores in your names?

Comment: Thank you for the warm welcome! I can't speak for Bella_, but I'm used to assuming that spaces aren't allowed and default to underscoring.

Comment: @Salmon_of_Wisdom: That was my guess as to the reason as well.

Comment: Oh, I see. Well, the good news is, you can have spaces in your display name. In fact, display names on SE sites are rather permissive about what you can have in them. :)

Comment: I just happen to be partial to underscores.  Matching @Salmon_of_Wisdom is a happy bonus. :)

Answer (score 9):

Welcome Bella_Blue and Salmon_of_Wisdom.

<\joke>For Salmon_of_Wisdom, I would recommend avoiding Security SE, lest you get [eaten](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/a/884/267898) <\joke>

<strike>Dog photos coming as soon as I can find them. (ETA 9 p.m. UTC)</strike>

[image: dog]

[image: dog]

This is Simba, a 1.5 (iirc) year old miniature Australian Shepard. He likes to run, eat bones, and pee (*a lot*).

Comment: I can promise to be patient o_o

Comment: @Salmon_of_Wisdom dog photos added :)

Comment: Well, The Bear doesn't frequent SecSE these days, so there shouldn't be any problem in splashing by :)

Comment: Ekadh - Thanks for the photos! They're unbearably cute
Nobody - Maybe it's time for me to dip my toes into the waters of security!

Comment: Eating the Salmon of Wisdom leads to foresight, of course. I'm not sure that any of the bears need it.

Answer (score 4):

Congratulations [Bella_Blue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1058732/bella-blue) and [Salmon_Of_Wisdom](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1081359/salmon-of-wisdom). Good to see more and more CMs. Best of luck for future.

Answer (score 4):

Congrats to both of you!

Bella_Blue: Your resume and depth of community management experience is very impressive, and managing a community of 1 million users ought to have *almost* prepared you for helping to manage the StackExchange network of > 16 million users!

Salmon_Of_Wisdom: Your love of volunteering, bluegrass, wisdom, and salmon makes me instantly happy to have you as a new friend :)

Answer (score 3):

Welcome both.

The first thing Blue and Salmon brought to mind was:

[image]

<sub>(Images taken from [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Pacific_bluefin_tuna.jpg) and [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Finding_the_homes_of_wild_salmon.jpg).)</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Congratulations Bella_Blue & Salmon_Of_Wisdom!
Good to see now 1001 CMs!

Comment: Not all 1,000 of them are CM’s. Additionally, many of the 1,000 have quit over the years. Currently, there’s actually only 13 CMs.

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica oh ,didn’t know that

Comment: Relevant: [Who is on the Community Management Team, and what does it do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99338/335251), [The Community Teams @ Stack Exchange and how we work together](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349266/335251)