# Please welcome Valued Associate #1301 - Emerson

Tags: discussion, announcements, community-managers

I've been so incredibly lucky and happy to have Bella and Salmon, [the previous newest hires for Trust & Safety](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371344/please-welcome-valued-associates-999-bella-blue-1001-salmon-of-wisdom), join me last year. It's only been 9 months, and I'm proud of the work they've done, what they've accomplished, and how much I've seen them helping folks around the network - be it users, moderators, or addressing tough world situations. As we took on more and more work, it became increasingly clear that just the 3 of us were not going to cut it, and that's where [Emerson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1232273/emerson) comes in! I'm so excited about him joining and the expertise he brings; Emerson has done a lot in this space and will complement our backgrounds nicely, I can already tell.

He has been working in Trust and Safety roles for the past 5 years, and before that worked in non-profits. Emerson started his journey by managing online communities on a well-known social media site, then moved into fighting scammers for the past two years. Protecting users and maintaining a healthy platform are genuine passions (sounds like a crock, I know). He is thrilled to join the team working to ensure Stack Exchange continues to be a vibrant community. He is extremely impressed with the work and dedication of the mod team across the Stack Exchange sites and looks forward to supporting all of you.

In his free time, he likes to spend time with family and his dogs, weightlifting, binging sci-fi, and playing tabletop games whenever they can.

Please welcome Emerson to the T&S Team as part of our bigger community management department! It's so great to have him here.

Comment: Welcome Emerson~! I am so happy to have you here! Truly the perfect addition to our team! :) :celebration commences:

Comment: Woohoo! Welcome to the team!

Comment: Emerson is a great hire, and I look forward to seeing him work!

Comment: They like me! They really like me!

Comment: Welcome to the team @Emerson o/

Comment: Hello to you, your family and your dogs. Welcome to you. I hope you work from home, with your dogs lying down at your feet :).

Comment: Whenever I see one of these the "Valued Associate" coupled with "#1301" makes it feel like satire -- if you valued them, wouldn't you use their name instead of a number? I'd just say "Welcome to a new community manager: Emerson!"

Comment: Ooh, what a lucky man he was

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I am excited at the prospect of supporting you all in maintaining the wonderful sites all across Stack Exchange. I look forward to listening to and supporting everyone of you.

I am starting to travel again and would love to hear any and all recommendations (especially off the beaten path). My next trip is to Buenos Aires and Argentinian Patagonia!

Comment: For anything travel, you should check out our travel community: https://travel.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Luuklag and what if he'll get hungry during the travel? ;-)

Comment: There is also a restaurants tag on Travel.SE @ShadowTheKidWizard

Comment: @Luuklag huh! Was hoping you'll recommend another Stack Exchange site, as Emerson sounds like one who make his own food. :-)

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard You mean [cooking.se], but he might also want to drink some [coffee.se] or [beer.se], or maybe he's even [vegetarian](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/). SE has a site for everything!

Comment: @Randal'Thor yes! That pretty much covers everything. :D

Comment: I have been looking for some communities where I can contribute answers, seems like everyone here is very fast on the draw AND informative!

I will try to throw my hat into the ring over at Coffee though. I don't mean to brag, but I have watched almost every James Hoffman video.

Comment: The bripe video's the only one you *really* need to watch tho :D

Answer (score 21):

Welcome, Emerson! It's good to see the CM team continuing to grow, and you're definitely a great addition to the Trust & Safety team in particular.

Looking forward to working with you – and playing D&D or other tabletop games with you sometime! :)

(P.S.: I love your profile picture!)

Comment: We should set up a mod / CM D&D game. It's [definitely possible](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/118089/pse-dd-chatroom?tab=conversations) to play D&D on SE, so that could be a fun community-building exercise. :)

Comment: What's a D&D game? Sorry I couldn't understand (or find anything online either) :P @Mithical

Comment: @DialFrost: D&D = [Dungeons & Dragons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dungeons_%26_Dragons), a tabletop role-playing game.

Comment: Oh, also... @Emerson You should check out the [rpg.se] site. :)

Answer (score -7):

Welcome Emerson!

> "In his free time, he likes to spend time with family and his dogs"

I look forward to seeing pictures of them!

Or if they're shy in front of the camera, or you prefer to keep their identities in stealth mode, can you share your favorite picture of a cute animal with us?

Comment: I suggest you probably delete that answer, its kinda awkward to ask people for their personal pictures without saying "may" or "please", Im just saying, either it should be reworded or deleted.

Comment: [A CM asked for something similar here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371344/please-welcome-valued-associates-999-bella-blue-1001-salmon-of-wisdom#comment1239502_371345) and the topic of sharing pet pictures is all over that thread and others. I was cognizant of the awkwardness about which you speak, which is why I gave an alternative option which is *much* less awkward. I agree with you that this post can be improved with rewording.

Comment: @user1271772 in the welcome you linked to, Cesar explicitly says "Yes, they would like to see a picture of your pet" and hence the pictures of pets in some answers. There's no such thing here, and each CM is different. So your request is odd indeed, while not voting to delete, I don't think it's something one should ask.