# Inconsistency in reputation (history) for new hire

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, stack-exchange-team

There seems to be something wrong with the vote-to-reputation converter or whatever it's called.

[This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/381313/295232) by the new Valued Associate received 12 upvotes so far:

[image]

but his reputation is only 21, which you'd think correspond to only two upvotes, except that his [reputation history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1232273/emerson?tab=reputation) only shows 21 reputation:

[image]

Moderators see somewhat less about staff user details than they do about regular users, but I'm pretty sure I'm not missing a -100 penalty for spamming or rude/abusive behaviour - that answer is their only post here so far.

Comment: [I'm seeing something similar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prL6d.png), however in the other direction, posts with <10 votes showing hundreds of rep.

Comment: Isn't this just an issue of caching or not enough time to update? We've seen this kind of thing before.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov that's pretty weird, yes. I can't reproduce that, but I did found out I'm confused by the tabs, so the situation is less FUBAR'd than I initially thought.

Comment: I don't have the screenshot to prove it, but when I last saw that answer it had 9 votes and the reputation was correctly showing as 91. Now I see 31 (for 13 upvotes), so I see the bug too.

Comment: @user1271772 my own reputation history is updating pretty normally at the moment.

Comment: Someone did an account merge and broke some stuff. ;) Should fix itself within ~15 minutes.

Comment: @animuson s/someone/animuson/ ? :P

Comment: @animuson So if I can figure out how to reproduce the screenshot above, it's something totally different? (my rep history appears normal atm)

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Yes it'd be something different.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This was caused by an account merge that failed to trigger a reputation recalc at the end of the merge. So essentially it attached the post to the new profile and then started incrementing their reputation again from 1, ignoring all the previously accumulated votes and reputation.

Deleting and undeleting a post is the quickest way to force a recalc for a profile. Now that the system has looked at the entire history, everything is normal. :)