# Old account of new staff member is showing up as a moderator here on Meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta, moderators, stack-exchange-team

As another result of [an account merge gone wrong](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/381317/295232), and similar to [Who is Samuel Ordonez and why are they a moderator here?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376974/295232), the [old account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1242204/emerson) of new staff member [@Emerson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1232273/emerson) is showing up as a [♦ moderator here on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Obsolete profile deleted :)

Comment: @animuson heh, nice 'reason' you used there :)